# How to access the internal memory if the screen is blacked out?

Tags: internal-storage, touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I dropped my Samsung Note 2, and the screen is now completely black. The phone opens & touch the screen seems to be only partly responsive because I can see the white previous & menu icons appear on the lower half of the phone.  I want to access the internal storage of the phone and store it in a different Note 2. How can I do that?

Comment: See [How to access internal storage or internal memory of Android while conecting to PC?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42157/how-to-access-intenal-storage-or-internal-memory-of-android-while-conecting-to-p)

Answer (score 1):

Turn on the phone, and connect it to your computer via USB cable. It will get recognized by the PC as an MTP device from wich you can copy files.

Comment: Some extra details please, so anybody else with minimal knowledge would be able to follow along. Thanks.

Comment: There aren't any details, you just have to turn on the phone, plug it in via usb cable, it will get recognized by the pc as an mtp device from wich you can copy files.

Comment: That was more info than your answer. A lot of people that search the questions and answers posted here are relatively new to Android. So properly answered questions are important. Go the extra mile, provide a link that reiterates your answer. Remember the SE community depends on accurate, qualified, and descriptive answers.  :)

Comment: If there is a lock-screen this will not work on new devices because USB access (MTP, ADB) is disabled unless the phone has been unlocked.

Comment: For this there is a trick: print a screenshot or a photo  of the lockscreen on paper at real life scale and use it as a guide to draw the locksreen pattern